# Split line every n characters

Tags: string, wrapping, words

I have a long binary string that I would like to split every 32 characters. Is there a command that can do this for me?

I have tried word wrapping, but it splits per word. It has no effect since a binary string without spaces is considered 'one word'.

For example, turn this:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Into this:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000
```

Answer (score 8):

For occasional use, you can do with `query-replace-regexp` (<kbd>C-M-%</kbd>).

Replace `.\{32\}` with `\&^J`. This means, replace all chunks of 32 characters, with the same thing followed by a newline. To type the newline into the replacemnt, use <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>.

If you want to apply this only to binary strings, use `[01]\{32\}` for matching. This will protect other text from being split.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string every 32 characters, adding them to a list:

```
(defun split-string-every (string chars)
  "Split STRING into substrings of length CHARS characters.

This returns a list of strings."
  (cond ((string-empty-p string)
         nil)
        ((< (length string)
            chars)
         (list string))
    (t (cons (substring string 0 chars)
             (split-string-every (substring string chars)
                                 chars)))))
```

Some tests for the code are here:

```
(ert-deftest split-string-every/basic ()
  (should (equal '("12" "34" "56" "78" "90")
                 (split-string-every "1234567890" 2))))

(ert-deftest split-string-every/with-trailing-single-character ()
  (should (equal '("12" "34" "56" "78" "90" "a")
                 (split-string-every "1234567890a" 2))))
```

And if you need to end up with a string, you can call `#'string-join` on the result:

```
ELISP> (string-join (split-string-every "1234567890" 2) "\n")
"12\n34\n56\n78\n90"
```